# How to change SVG animation duration without changing element's position on path?

Tags: angular, svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to implement a track simulation in Angular 9. In the very simplified example a skater starts with an estimated finishing time of e.g. 10sec.

```
<svg:circle r="10" fill="red" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00a2c1">
    <svg:animateMotion
        [attr.dur]="duration" 
        begin="0s"
        path="M 450 440 L 740 440 A 50 50 0 1 0 740 100 L 450 100 L 200 100 A 50 50 0 1 0 200 440 L 450 440"
        repeatCount="2" 
        calcMode="linear"
        fill="freeze"
    />
</svg:circle>
```

The initial duration is set to that value. But now comes the first time measurement. Based on the measured value the finishing time is re-extrapolated, which is now for example 20sec.

```
public duration:string = '10s';

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.duration = '20s';
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now comes the problem: when changing the duration of the current path animation the entire path is recalculated and the point jumps back on the path (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbknyt).

How is it possible to update/modify the path duration without moving the circle from the current position?

The behaviour I'd like to have is, when the measured time is slower than the initial value the point "waits" on the track. When the measured time is faster that the point fast forwards on the path... Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you could call setCurrentTime repeatedly to adjust things.

Comment: @RobertLongson I already tried, but setCurrentTime works on the current duration. When I change the path duration the setCurrentTime doesn't help, because I've lost the previous position. Or how do you mean it?

Comment: @RobertLongson please check out here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bags2w) it's now pure JS and SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we double the duration after 2 seconds then in our new timeline we need to be 4 seconds in.

```js
// Write Javascript code!
const anim = document.getElementById('anim');
const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("change")

  anim.setAttribute('dur','20s');
  svg.setCurrentTime(4);
  
}, 2000);
```

```html
<svg  width="400" viewBox="-20 50 1000 460" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <path fill="#defefe" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" path="M 450 440 L 740 440 A 50 50 0 1 0 740 100 L 450 100 L 200 100 A 50 50 0 1 0 200 440 L 450 440" />

 <circle r="10" fill="red" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00a2c1">
  <animateMotion
      id="anim"
     dur="10s" 
   path="M 450 440 L 740 440 A 50 50 0 1 0 740 100 L 450 100 L 200 100 A 50 50 0 1 0 200 440 L 450 440"
     repeatCount="2" 
     calcMode="linear"
   fill="freeze"
  />
 </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is so simple and logical when you see it...